# Angular - format input value in reactive form

Tags: angular, reactive

I have an input in my reactive form which uses the currency pipe. When I reset the form to its initial values, without having changed this price value, it loses the format.

If I've changed the currency value previously, the update gets done correctly.

It seems that Angular checks just the value of the input and not the view that is showing. I mean, if my price is 15, and it is shown as 15,00 €, when I do the reset, the initial value is 15, it hasn’t change. Angular alters the value but not how it should be presented. It seems Angular checks if 15 === 15 and given that this is true, it doesn’t apply the pipe format (even making the pipe impure).

So my workaround is to check if the price value has changed before making the reset. If it has, I can proceed with no problems. But if it hasn't, I need to use patchValue, without the price.

This is my reset method: (I got rid of the comments because they were in Spanish)

```
reset(): void {
    if (this.clientDataForm.getRawValue().contract.price === this.initialValues.contract.price) {
        const values = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialValues)); 
        delete values.contract.price;
        this.clientDataForm.patchValue(values);
        this.clientDataForm.markAsPristine();
    } else {
        this.clientDataForm.reset(this.initialValues);
    }
}
```

I would like to know if this is the correct way to handle pipes with reactive forms. I have tried to use the pipe directly in my component, but it doesn’t seem right to me due to it modifies the value, inserting a format in it.

Maybe is relevant (although I don’t think so), but I’m not using CurrencyPipe directly in my template. I use a custom dynamicPipe which calls the currencyPipe so my input component can be reused. I had a problem with this too because I could not get the pipes from an Injector. At least I couldn’t figure out the way to do it. So, I had to use an ugly switch to call the correct pipe. If someone can point me in the right direction to do this, I would be very grateful.

My dynamicPipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dynamicPipe',
})
export class DynamicPipe implements PipeTransform {

    public constructor(private currency: CurrencyPipe) { }

    transform(value: any, pipeToken: string, pipeArgs: any[]): any {
        if (!pipeToken) {
            return value;
        } else {
            let pipe;

            // I have tried with the Injector but didn’t work
            switch (pipeToken) {
                case 'currency':
                    pipe = this.currency;
                    break;
            }
            return pipe.transform(value, ...pipeArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

My input component html

```
<ng-container>
<mat-form-field class="seni-input-container" appearance="standard" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>{{ text.label }}</mat-label>
    <input 
        matInput
        [type]="type ? type : 'text'"
        [formControl]="controlContainer.control.controls[controlName]" 
        [value]="pipe ?
            (controlContainer.control.controls[controlName].value | dynamicPipe:pipe.token:pipe.args) :
            controlContainer.control.controls[controlName].value"
        [placeholder]="text.placeholder"
        [required]="hasRequiredField(controlContainer.control.controls[controlName])"
        [readonly]="readonly">
    <mat-error *ngIf="controlContainer.control.controls[controlName].errors">
        {{ utils.currentError(controlContainer.control.controls[controlName]) }}
    </mat-error>
    <mat-hint *ngIf="text.hint">{{ text.hint }}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I would not mix [value] with [formControl].

Comment: @kvetis But, how would you do it?. I do all the manage of value changes in the component, but I don’t find other way to apply pipes in reactive forms. I use [value] just to present the value.

Comment: I haven't done it myself, so I won't post it as answer, but try looking at this: https://netbasal.com/angular-formatters-and-parsers-8388e2599a0e

Comment: @kvetis. Thankyou very much for your response. I thought ControlValueAccesor was for custom controls. I’m just using a regular input. You pointed me into a different direction, and it seems weird to me the need of creating a custom control from an input, just to be able to use a built-in pipe. I’m very new to programming and certainly to Angular. Of course, not trying to question your well-intentioned response, but I can’t understand that this is the way to proceed with what I consider a reasonable common issue. I’ll take a closer look into ControlValueAccessor. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically you are creating a custom control - a control which formats the value, which is a simple operation and I understand it seems too complex to use CVA. But I believe it is the cleanest way of doing so because it provides you direct access to the values - both of the control and the element right in the control-to-element data flow.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @kvetis It took me a while, but the link you provided finally guided me to the solution. I made a directive and applied it to my input element. It’s a “simple” way to achieve my goal of formatting may input value.

Comment: I still have two questions, if you can help me. 

First already made: How can I inject the pipes in my directive so I don’t have to import one by one?. 

The second question has to do with the way to pass the FormControl to my input component (child component). I have kept using controlContainer to get the parent FormGroup and then get the appropriate FormControl. But is this the right way to do it, or should I pass the control itself as an @Input from the parent component?
Thanks a lot for all the help! I have learnt a lot doing this custom control directive.

Comment: I suggest you create new separate questions for that since I don't know if I can answer that. I can only provide my opinion for the second one - using an @Input sounds good.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!